# How to use React-Query as state management on server side in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query

(App router) - I want to use react-query as state management on server side instead of URL bc some are dynamic. Fx. I use `queryClient.setQueryData(['page]', { page: "home"})` on SSR layout.tsx/page.tsx to set query data and then use as the state.

When I navigate to pages where query data is set it works first time, but when I navigate back to the previous page or a page where data is already set one time it does not update that data. How can I update the data **everytime** I navigate to a different layout.tsx/page.tsx or is there better ways to achieve this?

Comment: This is a bad idea. There is only 1 query cache on the server, so it's likely multiple users will share the same data and that will cause bugs.
This also goes against what React Query is meant to be: an _async_ state manager. See [React Query as a state manager](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-as-a-state-manager)